# How to add slow log configuration in elasticsearch.yml?

Tags: elasticsearch

In older version of elasticsearch the slowlog will be in elasticsearch.yml but 
for new version like 5.1.1 we have to add like slowlog configs like
    index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 0s
    index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug: 0s
    index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug: 0s

I tried adding these configs in my elasticsearch.yml,when i started the elasticsearch service it is not starting it is throwing an error.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: In ES 5 you need to configure that in the [`log4j2.properties`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html) file

Answer (score 2):

Since Elasticsearch 5, slow log settings are for each indices.

You can PUT the settings to a specific index /index_name/_settings

with a payload like the following. More details are available at [Elasticsearch Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html)

```
{
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn": "10s",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info": "5s",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug": "2s",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace": "300ms",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn": "1s",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.info": "800ms",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug": "500ms",
"index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.trace": "300ms",
"index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.warn": "10s",
"index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.info": "5s",
"index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.debug": "2s",
"index.indexing.slowlog.threshold.index.trace": "300ms",
"index.indexing.slowlog.level": "trace",
"index.indexing.slowlog.source": "1000"
}
```